# C: Initialize structs as pointers only?

Tags: c, struct

Is there a way to ensure a struct object upon creation is always a pointer?

ex:

```
typedef struct
{
  int foo;
} blah;

blah a; // error
blah* b; // ok
```

Comment: A struct is never a pointer. A struct is a struct. A pointer to a struct is a pointer. If you ever make `b` point to something in this code, `*b` will need to be a `blah` rather than a pointer to `blah`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you want to ban declarations of the form `blah a;`? Are you trying to ensure that `blah` objects are only created through your provided interfaces?

Comment: I suspect you are trying to prevent your struct from being allocated on the stack. Can you confirm this is your intent?

Comment: I want instances of my struct to *only* be created through a function that returns a ptr, thus disallowing instances on the stack is helpful for the sake of tightness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure - you just need to hide away the definition of the `struct` into its own translation unit away from prying eyes.  Then, someplace else (and more public), just forward declare the structure:

```
typedef struct x blah;
```

`blah` in this case is an *incomplete type*, so anyone with access only to that declaration will only be able to create `blah *` objects, not full `blah` objects.

Another option is to change your typedef:

```
typedef struct
{
    int foo;
} *blah;
```

Now, `blah` is inherently a pointer type, and any declaration:

```
blah b;
```

Is in fact creating only a pointer.  Since the `struct` itself is anonymous, there's no way to create one except through the pointer-only `typedef`.

Comment: +1 *incomplete types* are the exact solution to OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apple uses this syntax a lot with their Core Foundation framework. They make heavy use of `CF____Ref` objects, like this:

```
struct __CFArray {
    // Internal Structure
};

// Copied from CFArray.h
typedef const struct __CFArray * CFArrayRef;
```

As a result, if you write code like this:

```
CFArrayRef myArray;
```

it is automatically a pointer.